# SoapUI + Groovy + Get 3 test data from 3 different environment respectively

Tags: groovy, soapui

In SoapUI, We have 3 different environment and 3 different test data property files.

So my problems are:

1. How to set 3 different end points in SoapUI?
2. How to get test data as per the environment using Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

I try to answer your questions

> 1.- How to set 3 different end points in SoapUI.

Set your test steps URL with a property like:

```
http://${#Project#endpoint}
```

And add the `endpoint` property in your test data file.

> 2.- How to get test data as per the environment using Groovy.

If you have a typical property file with key=value you can use the code shown below:

```
// read property file
def properties = new java.util.Properties();
properties.load( new java.io.FileInputStream( "/tmp/sample.properties" ));

proj = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;

def names = [];
names =  properties.propertyNames();
while( names.hasMoreElements() )
{
  def name = names.nextElement();
  log.info name + " " + properties.getProperty(name);
  proj.setPropertyValue(name, properties.getProperty(name)) ;
}
```

With this you save all properties in the project level, if you prefer to save in testCase or testSuite use `testRunner.testCase` or `testRunner.testCase.testSuite` instead of `testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project`.

Hope this helps,